# Hot to remember random value from array?

Tags: arrays, random

Hot to remember random value from array?

```
   public int getRandomValue(){
    int[] second = bubbleSort(convertToArr(generateUnique(10)));
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(second.length);
    return second[rnd];
}
```

Above code return new random value with every call of this method.

How to mememorise random value? And not generate new one, I need this value for using it in further.

Comment: I you don't want to generate a new random value, why do you call this function ?

Comment: Do you know what a variable is?

Comment: Also why would you need to sort an array if you take a random value from it?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the return value of the function to a variable and then use that variable where you need that fixed value